# Create a live RTP stream from images

Tags: c++, video-streaming, rtp, rtmp

i want to create a live video streaming via RTP (and using crmtpserver as RTMP server to stream), starting from normal jpeg images, in my own C++ application.
I was looking to the documentation of ffmpeg, libavutils and gstreamer but i couldn't find any information related to this topic. 
Does anyone know how to generate a live stream rtp from images? Any performance hint would be appreciated too.
Best regards,
Michele

Comment: i tried to use libvlc but the video streaming stops after 13 seconds.

Comment: the images are coming from a live 24h camera and processed, then stored on the hard-drive.

Comment: you can check out live555 libraries - http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I've solved with ffmpeg directly from commandline and i forward the stream to CRTMPServer